# Upon choosing a radio button how to get corresponding activity to display text?

Tags: java, android, xml

Android Studio.
When I choose a radio button and click the button I want the new activity to display the text that corresponds with the radio button

*The names were changed

First activity

---

```
public class CheeseApp extends AppCompatActivity {

private RadioGroup cheeseRadioGroup;
private RadioButton cheeseRadioButton;
private Button submitButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cheese_app);

    addListenerOnButton();
}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    cheeseRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.cheese_radio_group);
    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = cheeseRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            cheeseRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(CheeseApp.this,
                    cheeseRadioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(CheeseApp.this, ResultCheeseQuestion.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}
```

Second activity

---

```
public class ResultCheeseQuestion extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_cheese_question);
}
```

I am using Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

Use Intent to pass the data.

```
intent.putExtra("key",value);
```

You can get the data from the Intent in the another activity as-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String stringExtra=intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: thanks this with additonal help worked  RadioButton cheeseRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                displayResult.setText(cheeseRadioButton.getText());
                theText = cheeseRadioButton.getText().toString();  
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String theText = extras.getString("theText");
        TextView printText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cheese_reply_print);
        printText.setText(theText);